# MySQL Geocoordinates Update

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table containing lat,  long,  heading and speed.  I'm trying to build a query to update all records with a new lat and long based on the heading and speed in that same record.  The speed is in miles per hour and I am planning on having the query run each hour via chron.

I cannot get the query right and I have not been able to find an example via search.  Do any of you have this rabbit in your hat?

---

Ok, I am finally at a computer so I can clarify my question.

First, I finally have a working query but it's really ugly.  My host does not allow me to use stored functions or procedures so this (sadly) is what I have come up with.  I'm sure there is a better way to do it and that is what I need at this point.

Here is a snippet of my table:

```
 latitude            longitude           last_update         speed heading 
 ==================  =================== =================== ===== =======
 39.677788227038114  -98.194243140338530 2014-01-01 22:57:06   293 327.813 
 56.853391622132314   -3.402587399948705 2014-01-01 22:57:06   385 350.699 
-61.242651650343180  -40.628876992126585 2014-01-01 22:57:06   246 141.661 
 27.371112838443963 -450.507351636490900 2014-01-01 22:57:06   477 124.927 
-70.006806324344740  143.713340483057380 2014-01-01 22:57:06   246 176.172 
-25.174349398009255 -123.094903102322010 2014-01-01 22:57:06   498 59.9015 
-10.603401747579188  -62.931741014783654 2014-01-01 22:57:06   354 253.472 
-12.888452428740583 -208.069866383497980 2014-01-01 22:57:06   378 130.198 
  8.274645947879547 -359.522542922571600 2014-01-01 22:57:06   327 123.319 
 85.769466941975270  358.592792804086800 2014-01-01 22:57:06   303 180.456
```

Basically I want to update **latitude** and **longitude** based on the **heading** and **speed** (MPH) in each record.  I extend out the **speed** to a **distance** based on how long it has been since the last calculation.  Note that **last_update** is updated with the current time whenever the record is updated.

```
UPDATE Drones 
SET 
    latitude =  DEGREES( 
        ASIN( SIN(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS((speed*((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_update))/3600))/3963.1676) + COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * SIN((speed*((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_update))/3600))/3963.1676) * COS(RADIANS(heading)) ) 
    ), 
    longitude = DEGREES( 
        RADIANS(longitude) + 
        ATAN2( 
            SIN(RADIANS(heading)) * SIN((speed*((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_update))/3600))/3963.1676) * COS(RADIANS(latitude)), 
            COS((speed*((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_update))/3600))/3963.1676) - SIN(RADIANS(latitude) * SIN( 
            ASIN( SIN(DEGREES(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS((speed*((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_update))/3600))/3963.1676)+COS(RADIANS(latitude))*SIN((speed*((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_update))/3600))/3963.1676)*COS(RADIANS(heading))))))
        ) 
    ) 
WHERE 1;
```

I'm typically going to deal with about 1,000 records and this update is taking about 0.058 seconds on average.  SQL is not my strong suit nor is geo-calculations so your assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You should post at the very least, the query so we know what we're working with. Also; it's "cron", not "chron".

Comment: Is it the math that is tripping you up, or is it the SQL query?

Comment: Correct on cron though I'm not sure it's pertinent to the question.  I can try to enter one of my failing queries though I'm not sure how that helps.  I'm on my phone so let's see how bad I can mess this pseudo query up...  well I cannot add new lines with my phone.

Comment: Sverri,  it's marrying the calculation to the query actually. I can do the math and have many times in php &  javascript but cannot get it put into sal query format.  I'll try to put a failed example up when I get to a real keyboard.